# Dynamically add column content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have two columns table with multiple rows. Also I have some hidden fields to fill value in the column. Now I want to load values from the hidden field to table's column when some button is clicked.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>ACL</th>
      <td></td>
      <input id="field0" type="hidden" value="Access Control List"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bcc</th>
      <td></td>
      <input id="field1" type="hidden" value="Blind Carbon Copy"/>
    </tr>
    ......
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What the easy way to implement this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give your table an id, and you want to move all inputs into the adjacent td's:

```
$("#<your_button_id>").click(function() {
    $("#<your_table_id> td").each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).siblings("input").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't this more dependent on "input" box position in html? What if we move hidden text boxes in different section of the page

Comment: Yes, it assumes that the input boxes are siblings of the td's as they are in your example. If you want to move them elsewhere, you can target them by id $("#id") or by class $(".class").

Answer (score 0):

You dont need save the value in textbox you can save the value in html attribute ex : `data-value`

Try this way

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>ACL</th>
      <td data-value="Access Control List">
          <button class="show-value">Show Value</button>             
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bcc</th>
      <td data-value="Blind Carbon Copy">
          <button class="show-value">Show Value</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".show-value").click(function(){
    var theValue = $(this).parent('td').attr('data-value');
    $(this).parent('td').html(theValue);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the `input` next to the `td` elements, a solution is this. I am using `next()` to make reference to the next but you can use `siblings` if it is same level but can be before.

You can also traverse through DOM using `parent()` or `find()` if the inputs are in a lower level.

See working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3qw09a0p/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").click(function() {
        $("#mytable td").each(function() {
            $(this).html($(this).next("input").val());
        });
    });
});
```

Use document ready method to make sure your content is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Though already enough answers for this, just to add my approach:

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function()
{
  $("input[type='hidden']").each(function()
  {
   $(this).parents("tr").find("td").text($(this).val());
  });     
});
```

No id needed, just a button like `<input type="button" value="Click"/>`.
It also works with the table you provided in your question where the input is not wrapped inside a column which I would recommend for having valid HTML. Guess you just forgot that as you mentioned you would have a 2 columns table ;)